# How to determine if a PDE with two dependent variables is linear

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have this PDE : $\displaystyle \frac{ \partial^4 v}{\partial t^4}=kv\left(\frac{\partial^2 m}{\partial n^2}\right)^2$

and I wanna understand what's the reason it is non-linear PDE. I have some information about lineality when we have only one dependind function "u(x,t)" for example but in this case we have two depending variables...

I suppose the second partial differential term is not linear due it has a square power but what about variable "v"; it is a depending variable also, so I am wondering if it could affect the lineality of the PDE too?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Let $x=v,y=\partial^4v/\partial t ^4,z=\partial^2 m/\partial n^2$. Then, rearranging, the PDE is of the form $y-kxz=0.$ The function on the left-hand side isn't linear, so the PDE isn't linear. (The first term isn't a problem, and could be part of a linear PDE. The other term, however, is very nonlinear.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks for your help but I can't figure out how do you comes to 

$$y-kxz=0$$

could you extend more your answer...

Comment: $$x=v,y=\frac{\partial^4 v}{\partial t^4}, z=\frac{\partial^2 m}{\partial n^2}\implies y-k x z=\frac{\partial^4 v}{\partial t^4}-k v \left(\frac{\partial^2 m}{\partial n^2}\right)^2.$$ Your PDE states that the last expression is equal to zero, so $y-k xz=0$.